# При несуществующем RequestMapping возвращается 500 вместо 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http-status-code-404

При несуществующем RequesMapping (к примеру /fsdghfg/dsfgh/sdfghjk/dsfghjk) возвращается 500 вместо 404, ни один из Методов при этом не обрабатывается

Comment: Может быть Вы разместите чуть больше деталей, чтобы можно было ответить на Ваш вопрос? Лично у меня дефолтный spring-boot проект с MVC возвращает 404-ую, что логично. А это значит, что у Вас в коде где-то содержится ошибка. Но никто не сможет её найти, если у нас не будет перед глазами кода.

Comment: Если это 500ая, то значит и стектрейс должен быть какой-то

Answer (score 0):

Такое бывает, когда путь содержит двойной слэш.

В этом случае шаблон Thymeleaf не будет найден (см. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20155). Также Spring Security может бросить `RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL was not normalized`.

Для того, чтобы это исправить можно как-то нормализовывать такие пути, но это может быть небезопасно (и именно из-за этого Spring так себя ведет). Другой подход состоит в том, чтобы узнать какие исключения выбрасываются и сделать для них ExceptinHandler-ы. Если вы пойдете по этому пути, имейте ввиду, что не все механизмы для обработки исключений в Spring будут работать, так как вышеназванные исключения могут происходить на ранних этапах обработки запроса. Это особенно касается исключения от Spring Security так как он происходит в Servlet Filter-е еще до того, как выполнение дойдет до Spring MVC.